# How to hide CSS grid-area name display

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-grid

I am developing a simple UI using CSS grid layout and HTML. I have many grid rows and columns

This is how I have coded the CSS and HTML as follows

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>WP Desktop</title>
<style>


html, body, .grid-container { height: 98%; margin: 2; }

.grid-container * { 
 border: 2px solid blue;
 position: relative;
}

.grid-container *:after { 
 content:attr(class);
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1.8fr 0.2fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: "プロジェクトビュー Design-Area Design-Area Design-Area Outline" "プロジェクトビュー Design Source Others Outline" "プロジェクトビュー Terminal Terminal Terminal Properties";
}

.プロジェクトビュー { grid-area: プロジェクトビュー; }

.Design-Area { grid-area: Design-Area; }

.Design { grid-area: ""; }

.Source { grid-area: ""; }

.Others { grid-area: ""; }

.Terminal { grid-area: Terminal; }

.Outline { grid-area: Outline; }

.Properties { grid-area: Properties; }


</style>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="grid-container">
      <div class="プロジェクトビュー"></div>
      <div class="Design-Area"></div>
      <div class="Design" ><button id="btndesign" > Design  </button></div>
      <div class="Source"><button id="btnsource"> Source  </button></div>
      <div class="Others"><button id="btnothers"> Others  </button></div>
      <div class="Terminal"></div>
      <div class="Outline"></div>
      <div class="Properties"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have not given any text in DIv class. But the grid are displays  **test Design-Area**

How to hide this text.

PS: I am new to CSS and HTML

Note: Updated with complete code snippet

Comment: Is this all of your code?

Comment: The code that you just posted is guaranteed to not output "test Design-Area" on the screen, so you'll need to post more, and representative code in order for people to be able to help you out.

Comment: Set its 'height :0;' of class `.Design-Area`

Comment: Instead of giving just two lines of code, put all of your code here.

Comment: @All Updated the post with complete code. If you run the program you will notice that the grid area has text which i dont n\wanted to get displayed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.grid-container *:after { 
 content:attr(class);
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
}
```

Remove the `content:attr(class);` property from the above class. You're now adding a content to the grid area that prints your classname.

Comment: @TechUser No problem. If any answer helped you, please don't forget to accept one. This helps users after you searching for a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is this part of the css, in which you show the attibute as the box's content, which you apparently don't want:

```
.grid-container *:after { 
 content:attr(class);
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
}
```

Removing this removes the text in your layout.

Answer (score 0):

There is no display of `test Design-Area` unless you specifically put it there. So just remove the text.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "Design-Area area-two";
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
}

.Design-Area {
  border: 1px dotted grey;
  grid-area: Design-Area;
}

.area-two {
  border: 1px dotted grey;
  grid-area: area-two;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">

  <div class="Design-Area"></div>
  <div class="area-two"> Here is text, Design-Area has no text </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This code works. But my problem was wrt "content:attr(class)" . I haven't posted the complete code initially. And thats how you have given this answer. Thanks for the  help. Sorry for my english